# Error message displayed by FeedbackPanel does not clear on valid input submission in Wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I have a form where there is a dropdown and checkbox. When I don't provide any input, I get the error message set through the Feedback Panel as below code

```
private Form<ReportCriteria> createCriteriaPanel(String id, IModel<ReportCriteria> model) {
            SelectionForm form = new SelectionForm(id, model);
            ReportCriteria criteria = (ReportCriteria) getDefaultModelObject();
           .......
           FeedbackPanel fb = new FeedbackPanel("feedback");
        fb.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        form.add(fb);
       DropDownChoice<Project> billableProjectsList = new DropDownChoice<>(
                    "projectsList",
                    ......
                    new ChoiceRenderer<Project>("fullNameWithCustomer"));
           
            form.add(billableProjectsList);
            
            CheckGroup<Project> unbillablePrjct = .......
    
            form.add(new FormComponentValidator(billableProjectsList, unbillablePrjct));
            form.getFeedbackMessages().clear();
    }
    
     protected void onSubmit() {
                
               SelectionForm.this.getFeedbackMessages().size());
              TimesheetExportCriteriaPanel.this.SelectionForm.findForm("criteriaForm").getFeedbackMessages();
}
```

All the feedbackmessages value is empty and not retrieving anything.
I receive the error message from FormValidator correctly when I don't provide any inputs. When I provide the inputs and submit, the form refreshes and loads with the same error message.

I want it to clear when we provide valid input.

When checked on forums, I found for Wicket 6.x we need to use `component.getFeedbackMessages()`, but it is empty for me .

I am new to wicket. Please help with the inputs.

```
public class FormComponentValidator extends AbstractFormValidator {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private FormComponent<?>[] components;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public FormComponentValidator(FormComponent<?> selectedBillableProject, FormComponent<?> selectedUnBillableProject) {
        components = new FormComponent[]{selectedBillableProject, selectedUnBillableProject};
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.validation.IFormValidator#getDependentFormComponents()
     */
    public FormComponent<?>[] getDependentFormComponents() {
        return components;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.validation.IFormValidator#validate(org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form)
     */
    public void validate(Form<?> form ) {

        if ((org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isEmpty(components[0].getInput()) || components[0].getInput() == null )
                && (org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isEmpty(components[1].getInput()) || components[1].getInput() == null)) {

                error(components[0], "project.Required");

            }
        }
    }

private void configureFeedback() {

    // activate feedback panel
    final FeedbackPanel feedbackPanel = new FeedbackPanel("feedback");
    feedbackPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    feedbackPanel.setVisible(false);

    add(feedbackPanel);

    // don't show filtered feedback errors in feedback panel
    final int[] filteredErrorLevels = new int[] { FeedbackMessage.ERROR };
    feedbackPanel.setFilter(new IFeedbackMessageFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(FeedbackMessage message) {

            for (int errorLevel : filteredErrorLevels) {
                if (message.getLevel() == errorLevel) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: @martin-g , i tried most of the solutions using Session.getFeedbackMessages () , FeedbackCollector also . Nothing is working . Please help with your inputs .

Answer (score 3):

When submitting a Form Wicket runs all configured validators on all FormComponents (like TextInput, TextArea, DropDownChoice, etc.). If there is a validation error then a FeedbackMessage is associated with its respective FormComponent.

When rendering a FeedbackPanel Wicket visits all FormComponents and renders their FeedbackMessages (errors, infos, etc.).

At the end of the request cycle Wicket removes all **rendered** FeedbackMessages. If a FeedbackMessage is not rendered by any IFeedback component (like FeedbackPanel) then it will stay for the next request cycle.
This is done by [DefaultCleanupFeedbackMessageFilter](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/4ab85484b8d7376eafbe68cf1f812d9e87332646/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/feedback/DefaultCleanupFeedbackMessageFilter.java#L32).

Put a breakpoint at DefaultCleanupFeedbackMessageFilter#accept() and see whether the problematic message is being accepted or not.

Comment: -  i am not understanding how to implement the DefaultCleanUpFeedbackMessageFilter . Because in the page load , i have implemented - form.add(new FormComponentValidator(billableProjectsList, unbillablePrjct)); for validating my dropdownchoice and checkbox . Do i need to add something in onSubmit class ?

Comment: You don't need to implement DefaultCleanUpFeedbackMessageFilter. This is the filter that Wicket uses by default. Put a breakpoint in its #accept() method and see what happens. If it is not called then may one of your former colleagues implemented a custom IFeedbackMessageFilter that does something different.

Comment: i added the breakpoint and checked the getRequestCycle() it doesnt reach the FeedbackMessageFilter . In the existing code , they have used AjaxFormComponentFeedbackIndicator extending FormComponentFeedbackIndicator . But as i understand this is for one formcomponet validation at time .

Comment: But i need to validate the empty value of bith dropdownChoice and checkbox value together , how can i use this for the same .

Comment: i am not using AjaxFormComponentFeedbackIndicator , but using custom validator class extending the AbstractFormValidator . I am passing both the form components - dropdownchoice and checkbox value , performing the null check .  Using the div tag with feedback id to display the message in html .

Comment: You register an error FeedbackMessage with the call to `error(components[0], "project.Required");` but it seems you never render this FeedbackMessage in any IFeedback component (like FeedbackPanel).

Comment: i added a method to render the message from feedbackpanel using IFeedbackMessage filter  and called in the createCriteriaPanel method . Its now not displaying the custom message "project.required" . Am i missing something ? Have updated the code .

Comment: Your filter does not accept ERROR messages. So they should not be rendered by the FeedbackPanel. It is hard to help you more. It seems you don't read my responses. Please join users@wicket.apache.org mailing list and ask your question.